# JSoup "wrap" is not working as expected everytime

Tags: java, android, image, jsoup

I have an HTML string which contains text, images or map images. The HTML is dynamically generated. Now, wherever there is an `<img>` tag, it should be wrapped by a `<center>` tag. To achieve this, I use JSoup and I successfully apply that to static images and text.

But, whenever I am trying to post a map, the HTML is losing its structure. I do not understand what is happening. Both the normal and the map images have `<img>` tags. How can the method give different outputs?

This is the method which is doing the job:

```
public String wrapImgWithCenter(String html){
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    doc.select("img").wrap("<center></center>");
    return doc.html();
}
```

**Original HTML with image and map images before wrapping:**

```
<p dir="ltr"><img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-4de5af73-68f1-401d-9feb-1dfde1373cff-file" /></p> 
<p dir="ltr"><a href="15.2993265,74.123996"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=15.2993265,74.123996&zoom=15&size=960x540&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:!%7C15.2993265,74.123996" /></a><br /><br /></p> 
<p dir="ltr"><a href="22.572646,88.363895,-25.274398,133.775136"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=22.572646,88.363895&zoom=2&size=960x540&markers=22.572646,88.363895%7C-25.274398,133.775136&path=color:0xff0000ff%7Cweight:5%7C22.572646,88.363895%7C-25.274398,133.775136&sensor=false" /></a><br /> </p>
```

**Result after wrapping**

```
<p dir="ltr"> </p>
<center> 
 <img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-01516245-c773-4765-b542-ebecb964b255-file" /> 
</center>
<br />
<br />
<p></p> 
<p dir="ltr"> </p>
<center> 
 <a href="15.2993265,74.123996"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=15.2993265,74.123996&zoom=15&size=960x540&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:!%7C15.2993265,74.123996" /></a> 
</center>
<p></p> 
<p dir="ltr"> </p>
<center> 
 <a href="22.572646,88.363895,-25.274398,133.775136"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=22.572646,88.363895&zoom=2&size=960x540&markers=22.572646,88.363895%7C-25.274398,133.775136&path=color:0xff0000ff%7Cweight:5%7C22.572646,88.363895%7C-25.274398,133.775136&sensor=false" /></a> 
</center>
<br /> 
<p></p>
```

---

For comparison,

**Valid output with only images:**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p dir="ltr">
   <center>
    <img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-959467a6-f83f-44c6-b6fc-88ba4f49d900-file" />
   </center><br /></p> 
  <p dir="ltr">
   <center>
    <img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-46c38c96-c3b5-402e-a0b4-03209adf5203-file" />
   </center><br /></p> 
  <p dir="ltr">
   <center>
    <img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-626ec909-c65e-452c-a341-61a361584eba-file" />
   </center><br /> </p> 
 </body>
</html>
```

**Valid output with text and image:**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p dir="ltr">text </p> 
  <p dir="ltr">
   <center>
    <img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-11343a01-7cd2-4f9e-9f9a-025ec3feb828-file" />
   </center><br /> </p> 
 </body>
</html>
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

The methods in the class that are responsible for the above functionality:

```
private void createHtmlWeb(){

        String listOfElements = "null"; // normally found if
                                        // webTextcontains.maps.google.com
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + mainEditText.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ParseObject postObject = new ParseObject("Post");
        Spannable s = mainEditText.getText();
        String webText = Html.toHtml(s);
        webText = webText.replaceAll("(</?(?:b|i|u)>)\\1+", "$1").replaceAll("</(b|i|u)><\\1>", "");
        // refactoring html
        webText = wrapImgWithCenter(webText);
        // Determine link and favourite types to add favourite a class around
        // it.
        if (webText.contains("a href")) {
            String favourite = "favourite";
            // Parse it into jsoup
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(webText);
            // Create an array to tackle every type individually as wrap can
            // affect whole body types otherwises.
            Element[] array = new Element[doc.select("a").size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < doc.select("a").size(); i++) {
                if (doc.select("a").get(i) != null) {
                    array[i] = doc.select("a").get(i);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                // we don't want to wrap link types. Common part links have is
                // http. Should update for somethng more secure.
                if (array[i].toString().contains("http") == false) {
                    array[i] = array[i].wrap("<a class=" + favourite + "></a>");
                }

            }
            // Log.e("From doc.body html *************** ", " " + doc.body());
            Element element = doc.body();
            Log.e("From element html *************** ", " " + element.html());
            listOfElements = element.html();
        }

        // First need to do a check of the code if iti s a google maps image
        if (webText.contains("maps.google.com")) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(webText); // Parse it into jsoup

            for (int i = 0; i < doc.select("img").size(); i++) {
                if (doc.select("img").get(i).toString().contains("maps.google.com")) {
                    // Get all numbers + full stops + get all numbers
                    Pattern noImage = Pattern.compile("(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+))+%7C(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+))");
                    // Gets the URL SRC basically.. almost.. lets try it
                    Matcher matcherer = noImage.matcher(doc.select("img").get(i).toString());

                    // Have two options - multi route or single route
                    if (matcherer.find() == true) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < matcherer.groupCount(); j++) {
                            latitude_to = Double.parseDouble(matcherer.group(1));
                            longitude_to = Double.parseDouble(matcherer.group(3));
                            latitude_from = Double.parseDouble(matcherer.group(5));
                            longitude_from = Double.parseDouble(matcherer.group(7));
                        }

                        String coOrds = "" + latitude_to + "," + longitude_to + "," + latitude_from + "," + longitude_from;
                        Element ele = doc.body();
                        ele.select("img").get(i).wrap("<a href=" + coOrds + "></a>");
                        listOfElements = ele.html();
                        listOfElements = listOfElements.replace("&amp;", "&");

                    } else if (matcherer.find() == false) {
                        noImage = Pattern.compile("(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),\\s*(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)");
                        matcherer = noImage.matcher(doc.select("img").get(i).toString());

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Regex Count:" + matcherer.groupCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (matcherer.find()) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < matcherer.groupCount(); j++) {
                                latitude = Double.parseDouble(matcherer.group(1));
                                parseGeoPoint.setLatitude(latitude);
                                longitude = Double.parseDouble(matcherer.group(3));
                                parseGeoPoint.setLongitude(longitude);
                            }
                        }

                        String coOrds = "" + latitude + "," + longitude;

                        Element ele = doc.body();
                        ele.select("img").get(i).wrap("<a href=" + coOrds + "></a>");
                        listOfElements = ele.html();
                        listOfElements = listOfElements.replace("&amp;", "&");

                    }

                } else {
                    // standard photo
                    Element ele = doc.body();
                    ele.select("img").get(i);
                    listOfElements = ele.html();

                }

            }
            // Put new value in htmlContent
            postObject.put("htmlContent", listOfElements);

        } else {
            postObject.put("htmlContent", webText);
        }

        mainEditText.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout(){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Rect r = new Rect();
                mainEditText.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                // int screenHeight = mainEditText.getRootView().getHeight();
                // int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.bottom - r.top);
            }
        });

        // See if a trip exists
        if (finalTrip != null) {
        }

        // Want to put the location in the location section
        // if parsegeoPoint != null -- old information
        if (latitude != -10000 && longitude != -10000) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Adding in location co-ods: " + latitude + " : " + longitude ,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            postObject.put("location", parseGeoPoint);
        }
        postObject.put("type", Post.PostType.HTML.getPostVal());
        postObject.put("user", ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", user.getObjectId()));

        // Transfer these details
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WriteStoryAnimation.class);
        i.putExtra("listOfElements", listOfElements);
        i.putExtra("webText", webText);
        i.putExtra("finalTrip", finalTrip);
        i.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
        i.putExtra("longitude", longitude);

        if (mainEditText.length() > 0) {
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your story is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // finish();
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EditText Sie: " + height +
        // " : " + desiredHeight, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    // method to refactor html
    public String wrapImgWithCenter(String html){
         Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
         //adding center tag before images
            doc.select("img").wrap("<center></center>");
            //adding gap after last p tag
            for (int i =0; i<= 1; i++) {
            doc.select("p").last().after("<br>");
            }

            return doc.html();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the original HTML with image maps as comparison with the result? The way I see it now is, *yes*, it's wrapping the element, although not correct per se, but I'm more worried with the `<a href>` tag which doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: Is the problem about why `<center>` also wrapping the `<a>` tag, and why `<br/>` tags are moving around, is it?

Comment: @AndrewT. the problem is that, the <p> tags are not closing after the <img> tags and unnecessary <br> and <p> tags ace showing.

Comment: @AndrewT. the result should be as neat as the valid outputs posted above

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem, the code: [link](http://pastebin.com/rLx1Za3e) gives me the following output: [link](http://pastebin.com/2m1kDeFJ), which seems correct. Can you try my code? Are you sure there isn't any code altering your output? btw I have tried a variety of JSoups versions (1.8.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.1, 1.2.1, 1.1.1, and even 0.2.1b) all giving correct results.

Comment: @fonkap I have edited the question to include the functions responsible for providing the output. You may take a look at it and tell me if you think anything is altering the output

Comment: @fonkap thanks my friend you were right. Something was altering my output. I have resolved the issue now

Comment: @fonkap please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795112/remove-extra-a-href-tag-from-html-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue. Fonkap was right in his comments that something was altering my output. I just changed the place from where the `wrapImgWithCenter()` was getting called.

I have just changed the last of the `createHtmlWeb()` method and did this:

```
Log.e("listOfElements", listOfElements);
            //refactoring html
            listOfElements = wrapImgWithCenter(listOfElements);
            // Put new value in htmlContent
            postObject.put("htmlContent", listOfElements);

        } else {
            //refactoring html
            webText = wrapImgWithCenter(webText);
            postObject.put("htmlContent", webText);
        }
```

Now the output conforms to the requirements.