# Remove extra "a href" tag from html string

Tags: android, html, regex, jsoup

I have a html string like this:

```
 <a class="favourite" href="LixWQfueLU"><a href="LixWQfueLU"><font color="#009a49">Rohit Lalwani</font></a></a>
```

I want to make the html string:

```
<a class="favourite" href="LixWQfueLU"><font color="#009a49">Rohit Lalwani</font></a>
```

How can I solve the above issue? Should I use **JSOUP** or **Regex**? What will be the solution?

Comment: is it always gonna get two hrefs? Because I created a function without using `Regex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get your required string using substring :

```
String beforeString = "<p dir=\"ltr\"> <a class=\"favourite\" href=\"LixWQfueLU\"><a href=\"LixWQfueLU\"><font color=\"#009a49\">Rohit Lalwani</font></a></a></p>";

String afterString = beforeString.substring(0,beforeString.indexOf("<a href")+1)+beforeString.substring(beforeString.indexOf("<font"),beforeString.indexOf("</a>"))+beforeString.substring(beforeString.indexOf("</a>")+4,beforeString.length());
```

**Value of afterString :**

```
<p dir="ltr"> <a class="favourite" href="LixWQfueLU"><<font color="#009a49">Rohit Lalwani</font></a></p>
```

Comment: the result is <p dir="ltr"><font color="#009a49">Rohit Lalwani</font></a></a></p> basically its removing the <a class="favourite" href="LixWQfueLU"> tag and keeping both the </a></a> tags

Comment: New result is: <p dir="ltr"><font color="#009a49">Rohit Lalwani</font></a></a> so basically, the </p> tag is also missing now and please remember that this string will not be static the html will always be dynamic

Comment: Yes i know that string is dynamic not static but you have to given possible string.

Comment: Now check is it okay ?

Comment: New output: <p dir="ltr"><font color="#009a49">Rohit Lalwani</font></a></p>

Comment: So, it does not retain the <a class="favourite" href="LixWQfueLU"> tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64462/discussion-between-kittu88-and-haresh-chhelana).

Comment: worked.............but the output has an extra "<" before font tag: <p dir="ltr"><a class="favourite" href="LixWQfueLU"><<font color="#009a49">Rohit Lalwani</font></a></p>

Comment: It is also removing some other tags from the whole body of the html, some center tags went missing

Comment: @vks the answer is working but, in certain cases where there are different elements, its malfunctioning. As I had discussed the previous code with you, I thought of asking you to look at the issue

Comment: @vks I do understand what you say, I will be positing a new question with the edge cases that are coming up

Comment: @vks I will also post the link for you to look at it

Comment: @HareshChhelana please take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840538/re-factor-html-structure

Answer (score 2):

This code using JSoup will do the trick in a more generic way:

```
    String html ="<a class=\"favourite\" href=\"LixWQfueLU\"><a href=\"LixWQfueLU\"><font color=\"#009a49\">Rohit Lalwani</font></a></a>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element afav = doc.select(".favourite").first();
    Element select = doc.select("font").first();
    afav.remove();
    afav.appendChild(select);
    System.out.println(afav);
```

Output:

```
<a class="favourite" href="LixWQfueLU"><font color="#009a49">Rohit Lalwani</font></a>
```